# Unknown revision error when implementing Protobuf. (GO)

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, cosmos, protobuf-go, cosmos-sdk

I am coding at the moment GO with GitHub Repositories and need to pull a package.

```
go get github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/types
```

When I enter there comes:

```
go get: github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.33.2 updating to
github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.44.5 requires
github.com/gogo/protobuf@v1.3.3: reading github.com/gogo/protobuf/go.mod at revision v1.3.3: unknown revision v1.3.3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is a known issue. Can you try adding this line as a replace directive in your go.mod file:

```
replace (
        github.com/gogo/protobuf => github.com/regen-network/protobuf v1.3.3-alpha.regen.1
)
```

for your reference please check [here](https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/issues/8469#issuecomment)

Comment: This was already added but he still wants to import the gogo protobuf.

I have more than one go.mod

In which path is the relevant go.mod File which i need to change ?

Comment: I opened all go.mod files but every Cosmos File already had this change. I still get this error.